# Is it possible to find k-th quantile only from frequencies of a value list?

Tags: statistics, quantile

Suppose we have a discrete continuous interval [0, N-1].
And, there exists $M$ samples where each value belongs to the interval.

Now, we want to find a $k$-th quantile (say, 4th quantile) from the samples.
I denote the frequency of value $n \in [0, N-1]$ by $freq_n$ and $freq_n \in [0, M]$.

What we actually have is only a list of frequencies for each value, $\vec{f}$ = ($f_0, f_1, \ldots f_{N-1}$).

The naive solution to find the k-th quantile is aligning samples in sorted order and doing something.
Is it possible to find the k-th quantile from $\vec{f}$ without samples in sorted order?

In other words, can we somehow express the function $g(\vec{f})$ that finds the k-th quantile?

Taking a example for N=5 and M=10:

$f_0 = 3$

$f_1 = 2$

$f_2 = 0$

$f_3 = 1$

$f_4 = 4$

That means we have a sequence $\mathbf{X} =$(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4). But we want to compute $k$-th quantile only from $f_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase to make sure I understood your problem:

I have M random variables $X_1,..,X_M$  independent and following the same distribution as a random variable X taking values uniformly in $0,1,2,..,N-1$.
I observe the realized frequency of each possible values in my sample is $F=(f_0,f_1,...,f_{N-1})$

**Solution based of the sorted sample:**

you want the 0.1-quantile let's take the sample in ascending order: $X_{(0)},..,X_{(N-1)}$
i.e $X_{(0)}$ is the minimum

then k-th quantile = $X_{(floor(kM+1))}$ (k is the proportion of values below the k-th quantile)

**Solution based on the frequencies:**

$k-th$ quantile $= g(F) = \underset{j}{argmax}\bigg(\sum\limits_{i=0}^j f_i \leq k \bigg)$

The k-th quantile is the highest values j such that at most k percentage of my values are below j.

A sum of frequency allows to approximate the cumulative distribution function:
$\sum\limits_{i=0}^j f_i = \sum\limits_{i=0}^j \hat P(X = i) = \hat P(X\leq j)$

$\hat P$ are the probabilities guessed from the observed frequencies.
k-th quantile: 0.2-th quantile of a sample of size N=100 is the N*k-th (20th) lowest value in the sample.

**Definitions:**

A *frequency* is defined like this: $f_i = \frac{\text{number of observations taking the value I}}{\text{number of observations}}$

The *median* is a $\frac 12$quantile

Comment: Thank you for perfectly rephrasing my messy question and providing your excellent answer! Is the value inside the sum $(f_i \leq k)$ 0 or 1?

Comment: Or, is it $f_i$ if $f_i \leq k$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: I gave an example in the question. How can I obtain 2nd quantile (median) from frequency-based solution?

Comment: I updated my answer to add what I refer to with frequency and k-quantile. 

$f_0 = \frac 3{3+2+0+1+4} = 0.3$, $f_1 = 0.2$...  $k=0.5$ for the median

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I understand the value of $f_i$. But, I have not yet understood the values inside the parenthesis $(f_i \leq k)$ (what is the objective of $\leq$ predicate?). I'm wondering what value I can get if the equation is applied to my given example. Can you elaborate on it more? (Is that really $\max$ instead of $argmax$?)

Comment: You are right it was argmax I am really sorry for the confusion.. I updated it. $f_0$ = 0.3 means there is a 30% chance that your value is 0. $f_1 = 0.2$ means there is a 20% chance that your value is 1.
$f_0+f_1=0.5$ means there is a 50% chance that your value is below or equal to 1. 1 should be your median.

You want to sum enough frequencies (in ascending order of the values) until you reach the probability you want. At this point it means the last frequency present in your sum is the frequency of your quantile